# What should I edit in my previous questions?

Tags: discussion, support, editing

Two days ago I posted a question and today I am surprised that I can't post again.

In this five years, only one question was downvoted, but its ok.
So I am asking you to help me out to put things right, you can visit my questions and tell me what must be edited thank you.

Comment: autodidact - Hi, (a) Re: "*In this five years, only one question was downvoted*" That is not correct. Please review your question history, including deleted questions. Even some questions which had a *net* zero or positive score, in some cases did receive downvotes. (b) Please follow *all* the advice in [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/question-bans) article from the main site [help] to improve your chances to escape the automatic question ban.

Comment: I can't see if you deleted any questions, but deleted questions with negative vote totals count against you as well as the questions that were not deleted.

Comment: @JRE i delete only one wasnt down voted, reason no comments or answers to it.

Comment: @autodidact - Hi, re: "*i delete only one wasnt down voted*" That does not seem correct. I counted 2 questions deleted by you and 3 which were [deleted automatically by "Roomba"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/roomba). I think that [this link](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/deleted-questions/140351) will show you the list of your deleted questions (I hope that isn't a moderator-only link). || I don't remember if you can undelete a question (to improve it) if it was [auto-deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221). If you can't, then flag the question & we will do it.

Comment: @SamGibson "That does not seem correct" it was deleted two years ago i can screen and post my activity profile it doesnt appears i mean i only forgot thats all. "I don't remember if you can undelete" yes i think this option is possible thank you sam.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I didn't down vote any of your questions (or answers,) but I can see why you might not have gotten any upvotes:

1. Language problems.  It looks to me like English is not your native language.  You use odd expressions for common things (shortcut instead of short circuit, for example.) Not using the common English expressions for common things makes your questions look like you haven't done any research into the subject yourself.
2. Communication problems. You seem to have a concept in mind, but that concept doesn't actually make it into the question.
3. Misunderstanding the things you've read and therefore asking a question that doesn't relate to the text you refer to.
4. Very short questions that don't convey your understanding of the subject.
5. Arguing against the answers you receive.  You acknowledge that you don't know something when you ask a question (simple fact, people ask questions to clarify things they don't know or understand.)  Despite not knowing the answer, you argue that the answers you receive are  incomplete or incorrect.
6. Many of your comments come across as curt.  They have an aggressive feel to them because they are short and direct.

Much of the difficulties seem to stem from the language problems.  I understand how that goes.  I am an American, but I've lived in Germany for over thirty years.  I speak and write German fairly well (now) but in earlier times I tended to write in German like you do now in English - the minimum needed to get the point across.  Writing in a foreign language is difficult, so you write as little as possible to avoid mistakes and to reduce the difficulty in phrasing so many things.

Points 2,4, and 6 are probably direct results of point 1 - the language hampers you, so you don't put any background into the questions and then your responses are snippish because it is hard to be polite when writing very simple responses.

I've covered point 1.

You can see point 2 in [this question about heating in a short circuit.](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/580286/power-conversion-to-temperature-formula)  Your question asks how much power is needed to calculate the temperature of a conductor.  In the comments, it becomes clear that you understand that you need more parameters than just the current and the material but that wasn't clear in the question.  Your edit says that you would like a formula to calculate the power needed to heat a conductor to its melting temperature.  That should have been there to begin with.  It also makes it seem as if you don't understand the problem at all since you speak of power when it should be energy.

Point 3 [comes up in this question.](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/651721/how-much-power-can-a-6-nm-transistor-handle)  You are trying to figure out how a tiny transistor could handle 360 amperes of current.  The 360 amperes appears to come from the thermal design power (TDP) and the operating voltage of the CPU you were looking at. That confusion lead to a lot of comments that have nothing to do with an answer.  To top it off, you selected an answer from the comments that doesn't actually answer the question at all.  "How much power can a 6nm transistor handle" answered by "...processors have two main mechanisms of heating. One is static power loss (caused by leakage through transistor gates) and the other is dynamic power loss..."  does not compute.  It seems to have answered something that was unclear in your mind, but it is certainly not the answer to the question you asked - that goes back to point 2 again.

For point 5, [you argued against the (correct) answers to this question.](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/536399/digital-multimeter-display-count-range) The answers are all correct, but you keep poking because you don't see that they are correct.  That is irritating to the people who wrote the answers as well as to people who read the question and the answers.  It is obvious that you had trouble understanding the concept, but you also had trouble expressing which part of it you didn't "get."

Point 6 shows up in the same question and the comments to the answers.  You probably didn't intend it that way, but your comments to the answers are rather snippish - short, direct, unfriendly.

Point 4 shows up in [this question about radio signals.](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/537468/what-are-the-waveforms-of-radio-frequencies)  You basically state the correct answer in the question (even showing diagrams that prove it,) but you don't explain why you think you might be wrong or why you think there might be (which there is) more to a radio signal than a sine wave.  It leaves people wondering just what it is you meant to ask about.  Something is missing, but no one knows what.

---

It all boils down to difficulties expressing yourself and explaining what it is you want to know.  It all starts with the language barrier.  Trust me, you will not fix that in a short time frame (been there, spent years getting better at expressing myself in a foreign language.)

What you can do is to explain yourself more fully - even if you don't use the language correctly.  There's several people here (myself among them) who make a hobby of cleaning up questions and answers to fix language problems.  Do your best with the language, but don't sweat it.  It is more important for your questions to be complete than that the language be perfect.  We can (usually) guess what you mean from a sentence even when the grammar is bad.  We can't guess what thoughts you have in your head.

I think you need to expand your questions so that others can see why you are asking.

A few specific recommendations:

1. [What are the waveforms of radio frequencies?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/537468/what-are-the-waveforms-of-radio-frequencies) - What makes you think that radio waves aren't simple sine waves?  What is missing in your understanding of radio waves that made you ask the question?
2. [Digital multimeter display count range](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/536399/digital-multimeter-display-count-range) - Why do you think that the count number depends on the ADC reference voltage?
3. [Power conversion to temperature formula](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/580286/power-conversion-to-temperature-formula) - Edit the question to include the ideas you expressed in the comments.  Include what you understand of electrical heating, and things that you think might influence the result.

---

A final hint:

You haven't accepted an answer to several of your questions, even when to all appearances the question was correctly answered.

If the answers don't tell you what you wanted to know, then you need to fix the question so that you will get that answer rather than the answers already there.  That is, you got answers to the question as written, but you didn't accept them because they don't answer what ever it was that cause you to ask.  That means you asked the wrong question.  You need to ask the right question.

If the answers do tell you what you needed to know, then accept one so that the question is done.

Not accepting an answer leaves a bad impression and makes people disinclined to upvote the question.

Accepting answers will not have any effect on the question ban, but it might be a reason why you haven't gotten many upvotes in the past.

---

The bans are based on the number of votes (up and down) your questions get.  The system can't tell if your edits are good or not - an edit itself won't help.

The system can only tell if you have improved your questions by the upvotes they get.

Your goal is to make your questions interesting enough for other people to upvote them.  Upvotes go towards getting you unbanned.

Make your questions complete and interesting and useful to other people.  They will then vote for you and eventually get you out of the ban.

Comment: First I want to thank you for answering my question in details and in a way that's easy to digest. Yes its always 1 and 2, for the old questions I couldn't change them for credibility reasons, all I did is making an edits. And as you mentioned every time my question is misunderstood I add edits that make me look like am playing games to members wish am not, and for accepting answers there are two thinks: 1) in old question I didn't know that I have to accept the answer and upvote I guess I didn't have enough reputation.

Comment: 2) because I couldn't express what in my head as it should answer wasn't what I was looking for and there for its a responsibility to accept an answer.

Comment: Can i discuse with you points 2 3 4 5

Comment: @autodidact:  I think it would be more to your advantage to fix the questions with negative scores first.

Comment: am working on it :)